# pygraphviz OSError: Format: "dot" not recognized. Use one of:

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I want to plot the tree generated by DEAP using pygraphviz. I tried to follow the example in this [DEAP document](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/advanced/gp.html), but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 24, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xxyao\program\anaconda\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1399, in layout
    data = self._run_prog(prog, ' '.join([args, "-T", fmt]))
  File "C:\Users\xxyao\program\anaconda\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1364, in _run_prog
    raise IOError(b"".join(errors).decode(self.encoding))
OSError: Format: "dot" not recognized. Use one of:
```

It seems like should be some words after the `Use one of:` but there is not. My environment is `Python==3.6`,`graphviz==3.41`,`pygraphviz==1.5`.The `graphviz`and `pygraphviz` are installed via `conda`.

By the way,  I tried the following method:

1. install graphviz and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to system environment.
2. `conda install pydot`, `conda install pydot-ng`

but it still doesn't work.

Further infomation: Other layout provided by `pygraphviz` such as `neato fdp twopi` works well. Only the `dot` doesn't work!

Comment: Is the dot program available in the PATH?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to add the dot program in the PATH...

Comment: Please search for "how to modify path" on the internet or search stack overflow I think there are other questions that are about the same topi (conda, graphviz and path problems)

Comment: sorry to bother again. I tried the following method: 1, install graphviz and add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to system environment. 2, `conda install pydot`, `conda install pydot-ng`. but it still not work. Could you please tell me what is the dot program mean. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: In the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` there should be a program called dot.exe. You can verify this with `where dot`. When the program is present you can give in a terminal window the command `dot --version` to see if you can start it, If his succeeds it must be something in the conda pydot installation that overrules the standard path (I habe no knowledge of the conda tool / the pydot installation).

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. And solved it by executed "dot -c" in conda cmd.

Comment: Thank you sir!, this worked with Windows 10 and  pyton 3.8.5 in conda

Answer (score 2):

I made something that may be considered a bit of cheating, but hope it helps.
First, agraph.py takes into account the position of the directory so you may want to put the working dot ahead of the others

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz\\bin" + os.pathsep + os.getenv("PATH")
```

Then I changed the agraph.py file, which it may be located at "C:\Users\xxyao\program\anaconda\envs\rf\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1561 from

```
if os.name == "nt":
```

into

```
if os.name == "nt" or os.name == "dot":
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, just open anaconda Prompt environment
and type "dot -c" command and error fixed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0EMB.png)

Comment: If you find an answer useful, please upvote it, don't repost it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow  @Saul answer is worked for me. I think the root cause may be the `agraph.py` allow only limited PATH environment variable so even you add `C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz\\bin` still not work.

But be careful, I suggest the solution for this way should be secured by below

```
GVZPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz\\bin"
if (os.getenv("PATH").find(GVZPath))!=0:
    os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files\\Graphviz\\bin" + os.pathsep + os.getenv("PATH")
```